# Python/Django Elastic Beanstalk now failing on deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm working on a project that I haven't touched in about 4 months. Before everything on the deploy was working fine, but now I'm getting an error when trying to deploy an update.

*Failed to pull Docker image amazon/aws-eb-python:3.4.2-onbuild-3.5.1: Pulling repository amazon/aws-eb-python time="2016-01-17T01:40:45Z" level="fatal" msg="Could not reach any registry endpoint" . Check snapshot logs for details. Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03build.sh failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.*

In the eb-activity log, it further states *[CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/03build.sh] : Activity execution failed, because: Pulling repository amazon/aws-eb-python* before repeating what was shown in the UI.

The original was using a Preconfigured Docker 64bit Debian jessie v1.3.1 running Python 3.4. I've tried upgrading to the latest, which is version 2.0.6, but it never completes (don't need to get into specifics of that error, separate issue and I'd like to stay on 1.3.1 if possible). I've also tried upgrading to the latest 1.x but it has the same result of upgrading to 2.0.6.

Any ideas, or anything else I should be looking for clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker Hub has deprecated pulls from Docker clients on 1.5 and earlier. Make sure that your docker client version is at least above 1.5. See https://blog.docker.com/2015/10/docker-hub-deprecation-1-5/ for more information.